# Using Matplotlib Toolbars in Google Colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I am trying to create two horizontally stacked plots in Google Colab using Matplotlib using `subplot()`. When I make the graphs they get their width reduced but display correctly. To fix this, I tried using `plt.tight_layout()` with default values and by adjusting the `w_pad` argument but I am still not quite getting the look I am going for, which is two full-size plots on a single line. I am wondering how I can use matplotlibs subplot toolbar inside of Google Colab in order to adjust the parameters of `tight_layout()` until I get the desired effect?

The code I am using so far is

````
b=-2              #Romeo romantic style
c=1              #Juliet romantic style
d=1              #Juliet romantic style: cautious

def model(y,t):           
  R=y[0]                 #Romeo's love 
  J=y[1]                  #Juliet's love  
  dRdt = a*R + b*J*(1-abs(J))         
  dJdt = c*R*(1-abs(R))+ d*J        
  return [dRdt,dJdt]        

t=np.linspace(0,10,100)
 
y0 = [1,1]        

y = odeint(model,y0,t)

#plot solution curves
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
fig = plt.figure(num=1)
plt.plot(y[:,0],y[:,1], label='IC %s'%y0)
plt.xlim([-4, 4])
plt.ylim([-3, 3])
plt.xlabel('R')
plt.ylabel('J')
plt.title('Romeo the Robot')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

# plt.show()
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(t,y[:,0],label='Romeos love')      
plt.plot(t,y[:,1],label='Juliets love') 
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Love')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout(w_pad=1.5)
plt.show()```
which yields the output:
[![two plots of curves, one blue, the other orange][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DjEi.png
````

Comment: did you solve it? I am with the same problem @caleb-capps

Comment: From what I've gathered, Google Colab does not support the use of Matplotlibs toolbars.

Comment: I solved it - a different problem than yours - with `!pip install ---upgrade matplotlib`.